# How to show indexes in Oracle SQL

Tags: sql, oracle

I have created an index in Oracle SQl-

> create index ind_cname on country(capital)

When executed I got a success message.Now I want to see the created Index.
Please help in the syntax to show index.

I am new to Oracle .I want a query which shows indexes for the table.

Thanks

Answer (score 49, accepted):

**If you have the *privileges*, you can use the ALL_INDEXES or USER_INDEXES views**. The query would be:

```
SELECT  *
FROM    all_indexes
WHERE   table_name = 'COUNTRY';
```

If you want some information on the columns included in the index, you can select those from ALL_IND_COLUMNS. Documentation regarding these views can be found here [Static Data Dictionary Views: ALL_ALL_TABLES to ALL_MVIEWS](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/B19306_01/server.102/b14237/statviews_1069.htm#i1578369)